# Can the strings be changed into variables?

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

data1 = np.array([1,2,np.nan,4,5,6,7],dtype=float)
data2 = np.array([11,np.nan,9,4,5,6,71],dtype=float)
data3 = np.array([17,np.nan,13,4,15,6,17],dtype=float)


result1 = data1/data2
result2 = data1/data3
result3 = data3/data2
```

For every results, I want to convert the np.nan values into -9.0:

```
result1 = np.where(np.isnan(result1),-9.0,result1)
result2 = np.where(np.isnan(result2),-9.0,result2)
result3 = np.where(np.isnan(result3),-9.0,result3)
```

BUT In my real problem, I have hundreds of result arrays(result1,result2...result100). So, I can not do it manually as above. So, putting them into the group:

```
my_groups = ['result1', 'result2', 'result3']
```

How can I change strings (the elements of my_groups) into their coresponding variables?

```
for i in my_groups:
    out[i] = np.where(np.isnan(i),-9.0,i)
```

Waiting for good practice of solving it.

Comment: Solving it would be ***bad*** practice.

Comment: You can show good practice from the beginning. BUT the hundred result arrays are unchanged.

Comment: Stop using bare names. Put the arrays in a list in the first place.

Comment: Sorry I need solution after result1,result2...result100 are obtained.

Comment: Do it the right way in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

To iterate over variable in module scope you can use globals(), it contain all variable from module. globals() return dictionary with structure: {"var_name": var, ...}, i.e.:

```
x = 10
y = 10

print globals()
```

Among "service" module variables our `x` and `y` will be there:

```
{"x": 10, "y": 10, ...}
```

As for your example:

```
import numpy as np

data1 = np.array([1,2,np.nan,4,5,6,7],dtype=float)
data2 = np.array([11,np.nan,9,4,5,6,71],dtype=float)
data3 = np.array([17,np.nan,13,4,15,6,17],dtype=float)

result1 = data1/data2
result2 = data1/data3
result3 = data3/data2
```

Suggestion:

```
# It necessary to convert globals().keys() to list otherwise 
# exception will be raised that we change dictionary (owner new variable var_name)
# during iterations.
for var_name in list(globals().keys()):
    if var_name.startswith("result"):
        value = globals()[var_name]
        globals()[var_name] = np.where(np.isnan(value),-9.0,value)

print result1
print result2
print result3
```

The result:

```
[ 0.09090909 -9.         -9.          1.          1.          1.
  0.09859155]
[ 0.05882353 -9.         -9.          1.          0.33333333  1.
  0.41176471]
[ 1.54545455 -9.          1.44444444  1.          3.          1.
  0.23943662]
```

**UPDATE**

But I should note that best practice will be initially group your `result1`, `result2`, ... `result100`, ... variables into collections (the most suitable I think is **list**) and then iterate over it. The suggestion above can be "not bad" if you already has a huge Python file with these defined variables (`resultX`).

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your entire code like this.

```
data = np.empty(shape=(3, 7), dtype=float)
result = np.empty(shape=(3, 7), dtype=float)

data[0] = np.array([1,2,np.nan,4,5,6,7],dtype=float)
data[1] = np.array([11,np.nan,9,4,5,6,71],dtype=float)
data[2] = np.array([17,np.nan,13,4,15,6,17],dtype=float)

result[0] = data[0]/data[1]
result[1] = data[0]/data[2]
result[2] = data[2]/data[1]

result = np.where(np.isnan(result),-9.0,result)
```

So...
Replace all

```
data1, data2, data3,,,data100
result1, result2, result3,,,result100
```

to

```
data[0], data[1], data[2],,,data[99]
result[0], result[1], result[2],,,result[99]
```

And here is the code that replace all of these.

```
source_code = '''
Paste your source code here...
'''

import re

def replace_data_num(r):
    return "data[" + str(int(r.group(1)) - 1) + "]"

def replace_result_num(r):
    return "result[" + str(int(r.group(1)) - 1) + "]"

source_code = re.sub(r'data(\d+)', replace_data_num, source_code)
source_code = re.sub(r'result(\d+)', replace_result_num, source_code)
print source_code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign values to these 'variables' using a dictionary:

```
>>> string = 'result1'
>>> myobj = {}
>>> myobj[string] = 45
>>> myobj['result1']
45
>>>
```

To answer your question:

```
>>> array = ['result1', 'result2', 'result3', 'result4', 'result5', 'result6', 'result7', 'result8', 'result9', 'result10']
>>> myobj = {}
>>> values = [5, 2, 87, 56, 23, 5, 99, 2, 24, 15]                                                                       >>> for k in range(len(array)):
...     myobj[array[k]] = values[k]
... 
>>> myobj['result2']
2
>>> myobj['result6']
5
>>> myobj['result7']
99
>>>
```

Comment: your "real" question is a bad question. aj8uppal answer (before add-on) was a good one.

Comment: Yes, but I just posted the add-on for variety. DON'T USE `exec` IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT IT CAN DO

Comment: There, @lejlot, I deleted the offending answer :)